# How to create a histogram based on true or false in R?

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

What I'm trying to do is create a two histograms in **R**, based on if an employee at SeaWorld negotiated a salary increase and one for if they did not negotiate a salary increase. Could someone please show me where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Here's an example of the textfile I'm using.

```
emp   received   negotiated   gender   year
#325  12.5         TRUE         F      2013
#318  5.2          FALSE        F      2013
#217  9.8          FALSE        M      2013
#223  6.8          TRUE         M      2013
#218  2.1          TRUE         F      2006
#601  13.9         FALSE        M      2006
#225  7.8          TRUE         M      2006
#281  8.5          FALSE        F      2006
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
d<-read.csv("employees.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
str(d)

f1 <- mean(d$received)
f2 <- median(d$received)
f3 <- sd(d$recieved)



d$gender <- factor(d$gender, labels=c(1, 2))
pairs(d)

plot(d$received ~ d$gender)
plot(d$received ~ d$year, xlab="year", ylab="recieved")
m <- lm(d$received~d$year)
print(m)
print(f1)
print(f2)
print(f3)
abline(m)
abline(mean(d$received), 0, lty=2)


hist(d$received[d$gender ==1],breaks = 50)
dev.new()
hist(d$received[d$gender ==2],breaks = 50)
dev.new()
#hist(d$year, breaks = 50)
#dev.new()
plot(d$gender, d$received)
```

Comment: Where do you run into trouble? My guess is that there's some mixup with the "labels" vs the underlying values of the factor (which are encoded as 1 and 2).

Comment: @Frank Ok I fixed that. I'm running into trouble creating a histogram on how much of a raise the employee received ("received" column) based on if the asked for the raise or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` symbols in your data are causing problems for me...

With the `#` symbol...

```
d1 <- read.table(text = "
emp   received   negotiated   gender   year
#325  12.5         TRUE         F      2013
#318  5.2          FALSE        F      2013
#217  9.8          FALSE        M      2013
#223  6.8          TRUE         M      2013
#218  2.1          TRUE         F      2006
#601  13.9         FALSE        M      2006
#225  7.8          TRUE         M      2006
#281  8.5          FALSE        F      2006", 
    header = TRUE)
```

We get an empty data frame...

```
str(d1)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ emp       : logi 
 $ received  : logi 
 $ negotiated: logi 
 $ gender    : logi 
 $ year      : logi
```

But without the `#` we get...

```
d2 <- read.table(text = "
emp   received   negotiated   gender   year
325  12.5         TRUE         F      2013
318  5.2          FALSE        F      2013
217  9.8          FALSE        M      2013
223  6.8          TRUE         M      2013
218  2.1          TRUE         F      2006
601  13.9         FALSE        M      2006
225  7.8          TRUE         M      2006
281  8.5          FALSE        F      2006", 
    header = TRUE)
```

...the data as expected:

```
str(d2)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ emp       : int  325 318 217 223 218 601 225 281
 $ received  : num  12.5 5.2 9.8 6.8 2.1 13.9 7.8 8.5
 $ negotiated: logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ gender    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1
 $ year      : int  2013 2013 2013 2013 2006 2006 2006 2006
```

And for your question about **how to create a histogram on how much of a raise the employee received based on if the asked for the raise or not**:

```
hist(d$received[d$negotiated == TRUE])
hist(d$received[d$negotiated == FALSE])
```

Comment: Wow thanks!!! If I wanted to create a histogram on how much the employee recieved based on the "negotiated column" & gender would it be something like `hist(d$received[d$negotiated == TRUE] && [d$gender == M])`

Comment: close, it would be `hist(d$received[d$negotiated == TRUE && d$gender == "F"])`, with a few less square brackets and quote marks around the "M" or "F"